# How to Pass Access key and Secret Key shell variables to Redshift Copy Command

Tags: postgresql, shell, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use Redshift Copy Command through a SQL script,  for which I need to pass the Access key and Secret key through shell variables. but due to  the format of Redshift Copy Command, I am unable to pass the shell Variables.

```
COPY ${REDSHIFT_SCHEMA_NAME}.${REDSHIFT_TABLE_NAME} FROM  ${S3_SOURCE}  credentials 'aws_access_key_id=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID};aws_secret_access_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'  delimiter '${DELIMITER}' COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF;
```

The problem I am Facing is the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID doesn't resolve as they both are in ' ' one single quote.

On using the command as

```
 COPY ${REDSHIFT_SCHEMA_NAME}.${REDSHIFT_TABLE_NAME_BACKLOG} FROM  ${S3_SOURCE}  credentials aws_access_key_id='${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}';aws_secret_access_key='${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'  delimiter '${DELIMITER}' COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF;
```

the format of copy command becomes incorrect.
Is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provides a pretty good documentation.
I found what you're looking for by googling for: 'Redshift shell copy'

Here is the article with a working shell script:

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1143507459230804

I used this and it works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='my_access_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='my_secret_access_key'

REDSHIFT_SCHEMA_NAME='redshift_schema_name'
REDSHIFT_TABLE_NAME_BACKLOG='redshift_table_name_backlog'
S3_SOURCE='s3_source'
DELIMITER='delimiter'

cmd="COPY ${REDSHIFT_SCHEMA_NAME}.${REDSHIFT_TABLE_NAME_BACKLOG} FROM ${S3_SOURCE}  credentials aws_access_key_id='${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}';aws_secret_access_key='${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}' delimiter '${DELIMITER}' COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF;"
echo $cmd
```

Comment: what I am looking is shell variable substitution into script file, the variables do not resolve in the script file whereas they resolve on directly using them on bash

Comment: Could you maybe provide the entire shell script?

Comment: I have java code which takes properties file as input and script file as input and execute the sql query. I can pass the variables through the properties file. which is accessed by the sql script file and as 'aws_access_key_id=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID};aws_secret_access_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}' are in the single quotes the variables cannot be resolved from the properties file

Comment: one of the way could be COPY_CREDENTIAL_PREFIX=\'aws_access_key_id=XXXXX ";" aws_secret_access_key=XXXX \' and use ${COPY_CREDENTIAL_PREFIX} altogether but I am trying to avoid this approach

Comment: If you are using Java with two file inputs, why not use a templating engine instead of shell substitution?